# NSDateFormatter returning AM when should be PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a NSDate that I want to display in 4:00 PM form.

```
NSDate *time = [object objectForKey:@"time"];
NSLog(@"time: %@", time);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
timeLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:time];
```

The log returns:

```
2014-03-08 13:00:00 +0000
```

But timeLabel.text reads 1:00 AM, when it should be pm. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: change your date formatter. you have set it "h:mm a" make it "hh:mm a"

Comment: What is your system timezone? If you do not set any timezone on the `NSDateFormatter` is will use you systems timezone which may cause an offset.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` have `currentLocale` so no need to add it. Most probably the time you are receiving is in `UTC`. So you need to set the timezone to `UTC` where you are initially forming the `time` added in the dictionary.

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring...

Comment: check my answer your problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the timezone. The rest is fine. You have to give the formatter a timezone or it will use your local one

also be aware that logging with NSLog ALWAYS prints UTC dates

use `[formatter setTimezone:timeZoneXY]`

Comment: I did:  'UILabel *timeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    NSDate *time = [object objectForKey:@"time"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    timeLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:time];' but it still prints AM.

Comment: America/Los_Angeles is GMT-7?8?9? ... if your input time is UTC it won't work either

Comment: So I have to change the input time? I'm retrieving the dates from Parse database so...

Comment: whats the timezone of your input time -- likely UTC. so try to set the timezone to UTC if you don't want any adjustments

Comment: Ah. That was it. *facepalm* I just set timezone to UTC and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *time = [object objectForKey:@"time"];
NSLog(@"time: %@", time);
```

Your time variable time format is have 24 hour format. that way it display NSLog 13.00.

After that you have use to converter 12 hour format thats way it display am/pm style

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
```

Note:

HH - captial letter H is denote 24 hour format

hh - small letter h is denote 12 hour format

Comment: will give the same, the timezone is missing

Comment: @Daij-Djan It's a dupe even though it was answered 35+ minutes earlier?  I think you have that backwards.  Also you shouldn't be downvoting just because his answer disagrees with yours (I assume it's you that downvoted?)

Comment: @trojanfoe yip, Im sorry iDev -- I should have marked sandeep's answer as a dupe. I removed the downvotes

Comment: @trojanfoe I down voted not because I disagree but because that is what the OP has already. He HAS a date formatter but misses the timezone

Comment: @Daij-Djan That sounds like "disagree" to me.  That's poor form in my opinion.

Comment: why? because he states what the OP has already? it is 'not of great value' -- anyways I removed my votes for you

Comment: The answer wasn't wrong but just reiterating what was written by the OP

Comment: @trojanfoe is it ok to post an answer that just mirros the question? :) not to me.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I don't have a problem with downvoting per se, however if you have answered the question already I (this is just me, mind) feel that you shouldn't be downvoting other answers as this unfairly inflates your answer (not that there is anything wrong with your answer, and I think it's correct).

Comment: @trojanfoe I agree here and will vote less on qs I participate. I will still comment and flag it though. as it is (to be harsh) just mirroring the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code:

```
NSString *str=@"17-02-2014 05:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *datetoday=[dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *strdate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetoday];
NSLog(@"%@",strdate);
```

Comment: will give the same, the timezone is missing

Comment: his problem is displaying in the textfield